# How do you prevent a Flutter dropdown from hiding its parent dialog?

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown field inside of a dialog route.

Whenever the dropdown menu becomes visible it replaces the parent dialog.

Here is a video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcgOLK3t8UY

How do you prevent the parent dialog from being hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out.

The parent dialog route was extending `ModalRoute<T>` instead of `PageRoute<T>`.

`PageRoute<T>` implements the following:

```dart
  @override
  bool canTransitionTo(TransitionRoute<dynamic> nextRoute) => nextRoute is PageRoute;

  @override
  bool canTransitionFrom(TransitionRoute<dynamic> previousRoute) => previousRoute is PageRoute;
```

which prevent transitions to other routes that are not `PageRoute`'s (including the dropdown's `PopupRoute`).